# knex query elapsed time in batch update transactions

Tags: knex.js

I'm trying to update data in batches in a transaction, but after printing out the elapsed time of each update operation, I found that the later update operations took longer. At first, a single update took 129ms, and then each update took longer than the previous one. An increase of about 129ms

```
const updateFuncs = data
        .map(async (item) => {
          const now11 = new Date().getTime()
          let entity = this.removeUnusedKeys(item)
          entity = delUndefinedOfKeys(entity)
          const { id, ...rest } = entity
          const now22 = new Date().getTime()
          if (Object.keys(rest).length !== 0) {
            const query = trx(this.tabName)
              .where({
                id
              })
              .update(rest)
              .then((res) => {
                console.log(new Date().getTime() - now22, `each =======${id}`)
              })
            return query
          }
          return null
        })
        .filter(Boolean)
await Promise.all(updateFuncs)
await trx.commit()
```

```
129 each =======10532
259 each =======10533
398 each =======10534
526 each =======10535
651 each =======10536
798 each =======10537
930 each =======10538
1061 each =======10539
1196 each =======10540
1347 each =======10541
1475 each =======10542
1615 each =======10543
1745 each =======10544
```

And finally the total elapsed time is 1745.
It seems that the elapsed time of subsequent update operations will be affected by the previous data.
Shouldn't each update operation be independent?

Answer (score 0):

You are running all of your updates within a single transaction, this means that you are using the same connection for all of them. Therefore your updates will run sequentially rather than in parallel despite using `Promise.all`.

If you have your connection pooling set up correctly and have enough available connections, if you run the queries outside of a transaction you should see the results you expect.